# How to disable the back button in android C#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Im making an Android App using Xamarin.Android in Visual Studio and I've been trying to disable the back button in my secondary activity, and the methods I've been using is adding this code into the activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

So the code would look like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;

namespace The_Coder_Quiz
{
    [Activity(Label = "Activity2")]
    public class Activity2 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.easyQuiz);

            // Create your application here

        }

        @Override
public void onBackPressed()
        {
            //Include the code here
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

But that gave me an error which was:

```
member modifier 'public' must precede the member type and name
```

Im assuming that is because im doing the project in C#, what would be the correct solution since im doing this in C# and not Java (new to android development)

Im trying to keep off StackOverflow when learning but its kinda hard to find references online for Android Development in C#

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do Android development in C#? Are you using Xamarin (or trying to)?

Comment: The onBackPressed method is public. You cannot make a modifier more restricted but you can make it more lenient. For instance if you extend a class that has a protected method, you can make that method public, however, if the super class has a method that is public your subclass cannot make it private (or protected or package protected).

Comment: @Demitrian Im using Visual-Studio as my IDE and I've been programming in C# for over a year, and I dont feel like suddenly switching over to Java

Comment: @VargaDev But what framework are you using? [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/)? [dot42](http://www.dot42.com/)? It's not very clear from your post. You cannot simply write Android apps directly in C# without using any framework. It will not compile.

Comment: Xamarin, I dont think VS supports dot42, not sure though.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do an override in C# is:

```
  public override void OnBackPressed()
  {
        //Include the code here
        return;
  }
```

Comment: That helped! But I need to find out how to "Null" out the button, I basically want to disable the back button in the secondary Activity

Answer (score 0):

For example if it is a login page (Activity):

```
public override void OnBackPressed(){
 //by this way.. user want be able to hit the back button 
 // unless user is logged in

     if (user.IsLoggedIn()){
         base.OnBackPressed();
      }
}
```

Check this:
[OnBackPressed in Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936749/onbackpressed-in-xamarin-android)

And about android development using Xamarin, these are some tutorials:

- [Xamarin.Android Get Started](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/)
- [JoeRock on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Jx7ZNZL9dk&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l&index=1)