# Disabling back button C# Android Xamarin Code Not Responding

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

So im trying to disable the back button in my app and it seems like the code im using doesnt want to respond, its hard to explain in words so I made a gif so you can see it more clearly and understand because im not sure I will be able to explain in words.

I want to disable the back button in "Activity2" but the codes I've been trying doesnt want to respond to the back button
[image: Here is the GIF]

Ive tried these codes, dont know any more solutions since im new to android development.

First attempt

```
public override void OnBackPressed ()
    {
    base.OnBackPressed ();
    }
```

Second attempt (Both did the same thing)

```
public override void OnBackPressed ()
    {
       //  base.OnBackPressed ();            /*  Comment this base call to avoid calling Finish()  */
       //  Do nothing
    }
```

What could the possible issue be here?

Comment: Friendly note: Do not do this, unless you have specific reasons that is CRUCIAL (as in in 9999 cases of 10 000 don't do it). Disabling the back button is counter-intuitive and breaks the device usage contract imposed by Android. So i suggest you rethink.

Comment: What would you do instead? I dont want to be able to go back from the second activity, Im going to add more questions since its basically a quiz game

Comment: Well, why would you not want the user from backing out of activity 2? If i am playing your game, and i want to go back and choose a different category for instance, i would expect to press the back button, to return to the main menu. Are there any specific reasons why you would not want to allow it? How would the user abort an ongoing quiz? By needing to complete it, always?

Comment: I changed it so when the user presses back from any question, the user gets promted with the main activity (Main screen)

Comment: I think that would be the wisest choice in this case, yes, as you wouldn't want someone backing to a previous question. Also it is intuitively what you would expect to happen...

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    return true;
}
```

Returning true means that nothing will happen.. if you return false it should still do the default operation (going back)

This is the way to do it on a contentpage atleast... Unsure about activity.

Maybe try this:
[OnBackPressed in Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936749/onbackpressed-in-xamarin-android)

```
protected override void OnBackPressed()
```

and

```
[Activity ( NoHistory = true )]
```

did you check that pressing the back button actually enters your function?

Set a breakpoint like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7usZI.jpg

And start the application in debug mode  (F5)

Comment: I did not check that no, frankly because I dont know how to, Im assuming its through the debug mode?

and doing that code gave me this error https://i.gyazo.com/b7a41faf6c7a3493b03619ca03f05ced.png

Comment: `OnBackButtonPressed()` is available for Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Yeah im sorry about that. My override method was for xamarin contentpages. Ive edited my above post with something that might fix your problem. 
About checking if you hit the function. you can set a break point by 
pressing right outside the text area to the left. And then fire up the application using debug mode

Comment: Where would I add "[Activity ( NoHistory = true )]" sorry im really new to android dev

Comment: without knowing 100% because i never used Activity. I would assume you edit your current [Activity (label = "Activity2")] To [Activity (label = "Activity", NoHistory = true)]

Comment: This is weird! I tried debugging it with a breakpoint and when i press back it doesnt let me and if i press back again it does this
https://gyazo.com/88a5d97b08cf3d875c32c0d8e42798c2

Comment: Okay so the code above works but.. what?.. what just happend, im so confused, so the code worked but not the first time I ran it? and I did build it aswell.. weird..

Comment: It didnt let you continue in the app because the app was stopped at the breakpoint you set.. its indicated by the arrow now inside the red dot. To continue you need to enter visual studio and press "continue" or F10 i think. Cant really remember the shortcuts on the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

This code will get it to work, make sure you build the program and restart your emulator before you run it (I think thats what made it work for me)

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            //  base.OnBackPressed ();            /*  Comment this base call to avoid calling Finish()  */
            //  Do nothing
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked perfectly

```
 public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            // This prevents a user from being able to hit the back button and leave the login page.
            return;

            //base.OnBackPressed();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Just Like This

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: The only thing this "new" answer does is to repeat what half of the other answers are already saying.

Answer (score -1):

You can Try like this
Step 1 Add `[Activity(NoHistory =true)`
Step 2 Add 
`protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            return true;
        }`

 to your content page that you want to disable Back Button Pressed.

Comment: That's exactly what Jesper Christensen answered 3 years ago.

Comment: is this fixed for u ?