# Android: skip activities while going between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android

I have 4 activities A, B , C and D.

The transition is A ->  B -> C-> D. Now In activity D, I have opened a dialog fragment with an "Ok" button. When I click the "Ok" button I want to go back to actvity B. Till here I do not have any problem. But In activity B, when I click back button, I want to go back to activity A but instead it is redirecting to activity D. How can I achieve this?

P.S. I am currently working on Xamarin Android but I am sure the solution will work for both.

Comment: Please Check Darpan's Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to navigate back to activity B with the ClearTop activity flag.

More info about:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

and to use it:

`yourIntet.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);`

Answer (score 1):

- Use `StartActivityForResult` to start the activity D, and on press of OK button, user `setResult` to set some indicator that you want to go back to activity B directly.
- In activity C's `onActivityResult()`, `finish` the activity C if flag that you set in activity D says it wants to go to Activity B directly.

It will finish activity C and you will end up on activity B directly.

Here is a very good explaination of how it works https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

in Activity B:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, AActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

You can find Xamarin format [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18936890/4978534)

Answer (score 0):

in android :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

in xamarin :

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityYouWhantToGetBackTo));
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
    StartActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set activity B launch mode "singleTask" in manifest file like

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

After calling D to B activity your C and D activity will destroy.
Your new intent data route through from this method

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

}
```

For more info read [this link info](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-activity-launch-mode-e0df1aa72242)

Answer (score 0):

You can just finish previous activity using finish() method and onBackPressed() just redirecting the previous activity which you want.
For examples:
A-->B-->C-->D

onbackPressed of D class call C class using Intent.Like same thing in all classes.